# Mongoose find and findOne return entire collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the code below in javascript and the database is already populated. Now when I use either `find()` or `findOne()`, Mongoose returns the entire collection of over 6000 entries. Why is the filter not happening?

```
var tickerIDSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ticker: String,
  name: String,
  exchange: String,
  "_id": false
});

var tickerListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  complete: [tickerIDSchema]
});

tickerListSchema.index(
  { "complete.ticker": 1, "complete.exhcange": 1 },
  { unique: true }
);

var tickerList = mongoose.model("tickerList", tickerListSchema);


tickerList.findOne({"complete.ticker": "BMO"}, function(err, data){

  console.log(data)
})
```

**Result:**

```
{ _id: 5a44452bb1dac235f039c66c,
  __v: 0,
  complete:
   [ { ticker: 'AAPL', name: 'Apple Inc.', exchange: 'Nasdaq' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Altisource Asset Management Corp',
       ticker: 'AAMC' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Almaden Minerals, Ltd.',
       ticker: 'AAU' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Aberdeen Emerging Markets Smaller Company Opportunities Fund I',
       ticker: 'ABE' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Acme United Corporation.',
       ticker: 'ACU' },
     { exchange: 'Amex', name: 'AeroCentury Corp.', ticker: 'ACY' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Adams Resources & Energy, Inc.',
       ticker: 'AE' },
     { exchange: 'Amex', name: 'Ashford Inc.', ticker: 'AINC' },
     { exchange: 'Amex',
       name: 'Air Industries Group',
       ticker: 'AIRI' },
     ... 6675 more items ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an extra layer of abstraction that is unnecessary.

This code effectively creates a document with a single attribute.

```
var tickerListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  complete: [tickerIDSchema]
});
```

The result is that you have a single document in your mongodb collection `tickerList` that contains all of your data within that single attribute, `complete`.  Per the mongodb documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/), `findOne` should return the matching document. Because you are querying for a subdocument, the returned result is the parent document, which contains all of the data you have in your `tickerIDSchema`

To achieve your desired results, your mongoose code should probably look something like this.

```
var tickerIDSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ticker: String,
  name: String,
  exchange: String,
  "_id": false
});

tickerIDSchema.index(
  { "ticker": 1, "exchange": 1 },
  { unique: true }
);

var tickerList = mongoose.model("tickerList", tickerIDSchema);

tickerList.findOne({"ticker": "BMO"}, function(err, data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

Removing the `tickerListSchema` will allow you to query the `tickerIDSchema` directly.  The `findOne()` query would appear as shown, and `find()` should operate as follows:

```
tickerList.find({}, function(err, data){
    console.log(data)
})
```